# What's the difference between phpass and hash_hmac?

Tags: php, security, cookies

I'm trying to store a password in a cookie. Stackoverflow seems to recommend hash_hmac but wordpress uses phpass?

What's the difference from a security perspective and which should be used?

Answer (score 4):

This is a really bad idea. You should use `session_start()`,  which does everything for you and then you can use `$_SESSION` to store information about that user.  If you store a password hash in the database and use it as a cookie then you totally undermine the purpose of hashing passwords.   An attacker can use sql injection to obtain the hash and then just login without having to crack the hash.

Wordpress was vulnerable to this a few years ago.   That code base has had some very serious security problems.

Comment: Closing the browser loses the session. There is a secure cookie protocol [Secure Cookie Protocol](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~alexliu/publications/Cookie/cookie.pdf)

Comment: @jpiasetz i wish i could down vote comments.  Don't use this protocol.  If you need to store info between sessions then USE A DATABASE.

Comment: @jpiasetz this protocol does not address firesheep style cookie theft.  Its about storing sensitized information on the client side and makes the integrity of data susceptible to offline-bruteforce (Think of the new oracle asp.net padding attack).   This is a misuse of cryptography because the problem is avoided all together by using a cryptographic nonce as a session id and storing any information in the database.  Please stop posting this link,  its a bad idea.

Comment: @Rook – There's nothing conceptually wrong with encrypted and signed cookies. Poor implementations are, of course, a different issue.

Comment: @aaz  It is a misuse of cryptography because there are stronger and more simple systems that can be used in its place. "Complexity is the worst enemy of security" --Bruce Schneier

Comment: @Rook – Yes, and in some situations a cookie might be simpler, and you shouldn't discount it outright. E.g.: I'd prefer my settings to be in my browser than in PHP session storage on a shared host.

Comment: @Rook this isn't the most practical advice. Gmail, Facebook, Wikipedia etc. all use cookies. I would be happy with a comparably level of security to them. Pragmatics of the cookie vs. session arguement aside.

Comment: @aaz: storing `background=red;fontsize=12` is slightly different than storing `bank_of_america_password=<encrypted text>` in a cookie. Who cares if someone fiddles with the cookie and makes your font actually be 13.

Comment: @Marc – Properly used cryptography prevents fiddling, and a bank should be able to get the code properly audited. And it's not like you can store that password unencrypted in a database anyway.

Comment: @jpiasetz exactly they all use cookies.  `session_start()` also uses a cookie, because it is session handler.  session_start() generates a very secure cookie for you.  There is no need to reinvent the wheel,  no need to call `set_cookie()`,  just start using `$_SESSION`.

Comment: @aaz  Well I hope they aren't encrypting passwords,  thats a cwe-257 violation,  they should be hashing passwords.

Comment: @Marc B I completely agree.   The worst idea would have something like `user_type=admin`,  which is what snitz forum was doing.  They got raped by the asp.net oracle padding attack.

Comment: @aaz: properly used cryptography still leaves open the possibility of someone OTHER than the site owner decrypting the data, and slurping out anything they want.

Comment: @Rook Firesheep also steals sessions and the sites I listed don't use sessions e.g. have persistent logins

Comment: @Rook – And it's a CWE violation either way – that's why it's wrong, not because it's in a cookie. This is the Internet and at some point data has to be transmitted. That session you stored in the database? Probably backed up to the cloud.

Comment: @Marc – Why did the site owner give them the key?

Comment: @aaz: who's to say the site owner generated a good key? Ask the DVD consortium about their ultra-secure never-will-be-cracked-in-a-kajillion-years CSS master key.

Comment: @Marc – Then it's not properly used cryptography. And CSS is not AES-CTR.

Comment: No, but that's not say that tomorrow some amateur mathematician won't come up with a way to factor big numbers in O(1). If it's something that should be kept private, then it should not be transmitted. ever. regardless of how good the encryption covering it is.

Comment: @Marc – I'd rather take my chances with that than someone finding a relevant bug in MySQL (say, improper escaping by `mysql_real_escape_string`). And that database is going to be backup up and it's going to be replicated to a backup server and they aren't going to use a courier for that.

Comment: @jpiasetz you are mistaken.  In order to have a login you need a session.  In order to have a session the browser must keep track of a session id,  These are normally using the `Cookie` http header.  If someone obtains this value with XSS or by sniffing the wire (firesheep),  then they can assume compete control over that account as if they where logged in as that user.   To stop firesheep from hijacking sessions you must use https, this is the point behind OWASP A9.

Comment: @jpiasetz Anyway the whole point is that HTTP is stateless,  in order to have a state,  like "this browser is logged in",  then you need a session,  and in order to have a session you need a cookie.   `session_start()` does this.

Comment: @Rook – The cloud comment is: hiding the data in a database doesn't automatically ensure it won't get sniffed somewhere.

Comment: @aaz oah for sure, don't trust your database and don't trust your employees.  A salt+hashed password embodies this.